# Is it possible to use prefix as param ir Laravel routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I have different languages on the page and I'm wondering is it possible to use them as prefix param. Something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'BlogController@posts');
})->where('lang', '(en|fr|de)');
```

Comment: you can write a middleware for this

Comment: @astro could you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry i understood the question incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The closest i could think of was this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'BlogController@posts')->where('lang', '(en|fr|de)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code get language from your languages table. Hope you can change this code to your requirements, if not - ask ;) try to help you..

Model

```
class Language() {

public $table = 'languages';
public $timestamps = false;

public function set() {
    $code = Request::segment(1);
    $language = Language::whereCode($code)->first();
    return $language;
}
```

Router

```
$language = new Language();
$language->set();    

Route::get('/', function() use ($language) { 
    return Redirect::to('/' . $language->code);
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => $language->code), function() {  
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PageController@index'));
});
```